# How can i create and trigger custom events in Framer Studio (Framer.js) using coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, eventtrigger, custom-events, framerjs

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)
This article demonstrates how to create and dispatch DOM events. Such events are commonly called synthetic events, as opposed to the events fired by the browser itself.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the given JS to coffeescript?

Comment: I know how to convert it to cs, but how can use it inside framer ? to create a custom event, to trigger it from a layer element , to catch event by a containing layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Got this link from Framer group at FB.](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-08/decouple-your-apps-with-eventdriven-coffeescript)

Here is a simple cs example that works for my needs

```
# npm install events
EventsEmitter = require('events')

class customEvent extends EventsEmitter
    constructor: ->
        @on "startScan", -> startAppsScan()
        @on "cancelScan", -> cancelScan()

startScanButton = new Layer
    x: Align.center
    y: Align.center(-150)
    backgroundColor: "yellow"

cancelScanButton = new Layer
    x: Align.center
    y: Align.center(150)
    backgroundColor: "red"

startScanButton.onClick ->
    evt = new customEvent
    evt.emit "startScan"

cancelScanButton.onClick ->
    evt = new customEvent
    evt.emit "cancelScan"

startAppsScan = ->
    print "starting scan...."

cancelScan = ->
    print "scan is cancelled !"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but probably you want custom events on Framer `Layer` objects, right?

The `Layer` object has some nice shorthand functions for this: `on()` and `emit()`. You use them like this:

```
layer = new Layer

customEventName = "something"

layer.on customEventName, (argument, layer) ->
    print "Custom event", argument, layer

layer.emit customEventName, 1

layer.emit customEventName, 2
```

This prints out the following:

```
» "Custom event", 1, <Layer layer id:1 (0, 0) 200x200>
» "Custom event", 2, <Layer layer id:1 (0, 0) 200x200>
```

Comment: Thanks Niels. I didn't know this is possible and tried all sorts of workarounds. What about event bubbling ? can an parent layer listen to a child layer that fires a custom event ?

Comment: I don't think we bubble custom events automatically. You can obviously set this up yourself, but that's a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks again. If it's not too much trouble can you show how to set it up ? a code example ?